# Property whose type is OBLIGATORY an enum value

Tags: ios, objective-c, enums, properties

I want my class to have a property that can only be assigned a value from an enum, this is my header file:

```
@interface Terminal : NSObject

NS_ENUM(NSInteger, TerminalType) {
    tOnline,
    tOffline
};

@property (nonatomic,assign) TerminalType type;

@end
```

The problem is that although apparently everything is correct, I can assign any value to the property with a set

```
Terminal *t = [[Terminal alloc] init];
t.type = 54;
```

How should I implement the class so that the property only supports the values ​​defined in the enum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objective-C enums are C enums and C enums allow this, although you probably get a warning at the place of assignment. You can implement your own property setter in which you check for all valid values and `@throw` an `NSException` otherwise.

If the [`NS_CLOSED_ENUM`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/objective-c_and_c_code_customization/grouping_related_objective-c_constants) macro fits and is available in your SDK, it may be a good idea to use it instead of the `NS_ENUM` macro, since it tells the compiler explicitly that no other values will become valid in the future, and which will probably make the compiler issue stricter warnings for values it knows to be bad.

Comment: Hi - I agree with this solution ... but ... to throw an exception is maybe a bit heavy. You could also follow C approach e.g. and set to tOffLine for 0 and to tOnLine for anything else. So you do not throw exception, but you use your custom setter to standardise the value. This is nice thing about Objective-C as it allows you to do so. Anyhow, solution will depend on your specific needs but keep this in mind.

Comment: Obviously what's appropriate depends on the context. If it's setting a value from your own code when you should know better, throwing an exception allows you to notice it immediately. If it involves taking unseen information from the outside, defaulting to a known value could be the right thing, but it could also be a sign that the source of data is bogus and should be handled, which it could be with `@try`. Correcting one "off" field to a known good value and continuing could be both confusing, dangerous and difficult to debug.

Comment: Also, of course working with exceptions instead of `NSError` if you're expecting things to possibly be out of range isn't very Cocoa-like. (Exceptions are meant to only be used for things the programmer messed up and can fix in the code.) A property setter doesn't allow `NSError`. If accepting values that could be out of range is an issue, you could also make a setter method that takes an `NSError **` and returns `BOOL`.

Comment: I will implement as you recommend, my own setter. I'm translating code from java, and these little things are a headache.